# -1 Hour timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i have the following timestamp : 1445086800

I want to do - 1 hour on this timestamp. 
What is the best way to do this in javascript? 
The output needs to be a unix timestamp also.

Is there something like a strtotime() in javascript function?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code to show us how you have already tried to solve this, and explain what was wrong with it.

Comment: Just substract a hour: `ts - 3600e3`

Comment: Re: `strtotime()`, you can use `Date.parse()`.  Just remember that JavaScript's `Date.parse()` returns milliseconds, where PHP's `strtotime()` returns seconds, so `Date.parse("Jan 1, 2016")` returns `1451624400000`, where `strtotime("Jan 1, 2016")` returns `1451606400`.

Comment: @jpec—no, **do not do that**. *Date.parse* expects a string, not a number, and it's implementation dependent so while the result should be an invalid date (since `1445086800` will converted to a string and interpreted as a year that is beyond the max year for javascript dates of 287396), it might be anything.

Comment: @RobG The question was, "Is there something like strototime() in javascript?", and the answer is "yes", there is.  It does expect a string, just like strtotime() does.  Implementation may vary, however for common date / time string formats, I'm getting consistent results in all major browsers, and back to IE 5.

Comment: @jpec–perhaps those common formats did not include 2016-06-01, which isn't treated consistently even by current browsers, much less back to IE 5 (which will return an invalid date). The language specification specifically says that parsing of **any** format other than ISO 8601 is implementation dependent, and even parsing of specification–compliant ISO formats is not consistent in current browsers. *Date.parse* will not correctly parse `1445086800` as a number or string.

Comment: @RobG - With just a quick test, trying `Date.parse('2016-06-01')` results in `1464739200000` in the following latest browsers and IE: Chrome (Windows, Android, Mac), Firefox (Windows, Mac), Safari (Mac), IE (9,10,11, Edge). IE 8 and below return `NaN`.  Incidentally, PHP's `strtotime()` will not correctly parse `1445086800` as an int or a string, either.

Comment: @jpec—So you've confirmed that *Date.parse* is inconsistent across browsers in use. That was my point and the reason its use is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @RobG: If you are targeting IE <= 8, definitely avoid Date.parse.  I proved that Date.parse is consistent in current browsers for your given example format, `2016-06-01`.  If you can verify that Date.parse returns a consistent value across browsers for a known date format, what's the harm in using it?

Comment: @jpec—there are recent, in–use versions of current browsers that will parse ISO 8601 dates as local, others as UTC and some allow out of range values. It's not a matter targeting but robustly dealing with those actually in use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do this

```
timestamp = timestamp - 3600
```

you have to subtract 3600 seconds to the timestamp var
If your timestamp is in milliseconds  multiply by 1000 the 3600 to get in seconds

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamps are counted in seconds. Thus, to substract 1 hour:

```
timestamp -= 3600; // 60 seconds * 60 minutes
```

Your new timestemp will be:

```
1445083200
```